# Variable only updates once after running code - Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I made an embed message send with arrow reactions so you can flip the page like a "book" to see more. It all works except I can't figure out why `facts_page` only updates once. I'll react with the right arrow and it'll flip to the second page and add 1 to `facts_page` but after that it won't go any higher. I can flip left and right but only 1 point up or down.

```py
    async def on_reaction_add(self, reaction, user):
        with open('guild_settings.json', 'r') as file:
            guild_settings = json.loads(file.read())
        guild_id = str(reaction.message.guild.id)
        facts_page = 3
        message_id = reaction.message.id
        channel = reaction.message.channel
        msg = await channel.fetch_message(message_id)
        embed_title = msg.embeds[0].title
        if embed_title == "Here are the random facts that will send at your given time periods:" and user.id != 753479351139303484:
            await msg.remove_reaction(reaction, user)
            if str(reaction) == "⬅️" and facts_page >= 2:
                facts_page -= 1
            if str(reaction) == "➡️":
                facts_page += 1
        print(f"{str(reaction)}, {facts_page}")

        facts_display = ""
        facts = []
        for fact_name, fact in guild_settings[guild_id]["random_facts"].items():
            item = f"{fact_name} - {fact}"
            facts.append(item)
        max_iteration = 8 * facts_page
        min_iteration = 8 * (facts_page - 1)
        fact_list = facts[min_iteration:max_iteration]
        for fact in fact_list:
            facts_display += f"{fact}\n\n"
        embedvar = discord.Embed(title=f"Here are the random facts that will send at your given time "
                                       f"periods:",
                                 description=f"Page {facts_page}\n" + facts_display,
                                 color=0x00ff00)
        await msg.edit(embed=embedvar)
```

Comment: Can you provide a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: If you found a solution you should consider posting it here to help those who find this in the future!

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer a discord user gave me.

Easiest way : use [discord.ext.menus](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord-ext-menus) (beta stuff)

Or if you want to use that way :

1. you are re-fetching the message, that's useless : reaction.message is already the message (random comment)
2. you redefine fact_pages as 3 on every run <- **ISSUE HERE**